# Systemd enabled services not starting anymore

Tags: systemd

I made some custom systemd services long time ago, all have the same configuration (except for the ExecStart of course)

This configuration worked for years, I have ubuntu up and running since version 18.04 LTS, but now looks like some of these systemd services aren't starting at boot at all, the configuration is as follow (myapp.service):

```
[Unit]
Description="myapp"
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myapp
KillMode=control-group

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is enabled:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable myapp
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myapp.service → /lib/systemd/system/myapp.service.
```

If i do "systemctl status myapp" after a reboot:

```
● myapp.service - "myapp"
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

If i do "journalctl -u myapp -f" after a reboot:

```
Jan 13 12:10:06 myhost systemd[1]: Started myapp.
Jan 17 07:15:03 myhost systemd[1]: Stopping myapp...
Jan 17 07:15:09 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped myapp.
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: Nope, i have never solved it. Ended up in reinstalling everything.